# Exclude status check logs from Datadog

Tags: logging, filter, google-kubernetes-engine, datadog, kong

I am using `Datadog` for collecting logs and metrics from services running in `Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)`. I have configured `Datadog` with specific inclusion and exclusion rules for collecting logs, and I'm encountering an issue with excluding `Kong` status check logs.

My current Datadog configuration in `datadog-values.yaml` looks like this:

```
datadog:
  apiKeyExistingSecret: datadog-secret
  apm:
    instrumentation:
      enabled: true
  site: datadoghq.eu 
  logs:
    enabled: true
    containerCollectAll: true
  env: 
    - name: DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE_LOGS
      value: image:.*
    - name: DD_CONTAINER_INCLUDE_LOGS
      value: image:.*kong.* image:.*alore.*
```

I want to exclude logs generated by Kong status checks, specifically those with the request pattern `"GET /status HTTP/2.0"`.

To achieve this, I attempted to add a log processing rule using the `DD_LOGS_CONFIG_PROCESSING_RULES` environment variable:

```
env:
  - name: DD_LOGS_CONFIG_PROCESSING_RULES
    value: '[{"type": "exclude_at_match", "name": "exclude_healthcheck_logs", "pattern" : "^GET /status http/2\.0$"}]'
```

However, after adding this environment variable to my `datadog-values.yaml`, `Kong` logs stopped appearing in `Datadog`.

I expect `Kong` logs to continue coming into `Datadog`, while excluding logs related to the status checks.

I am seeking guidance on how to properly configure `Datadog` to achieve this exclusion while ensuring that `Kong` logs are still collected.

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can drop them in the log pipeline inside datadog using the GUI can be easier to check your pattern

Comment: I have solved it. Removed the unnecessary signs in `pattern`  and the status check logs are not coming

corrected version:
`env:
  - name: DD_LOGS_CONFIG_PROCESSING_RULES
    value: '[{"type": "exclude_at_match", "name": "exclude_healthcheck_logs", "pattern" : "GET /status HTTP/2.0$"}]'`